# Extracting an integer between = and ;

Tags: python, regex, file-io, readline

Given the following string;

```
....00.3276021,,,constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00...
```

How can I extract the values for `constString1` and `constString2` so that I can assign them to a variable. For example:

```
string1_cummulativeTotal += [the magic returning the int]
string2_cummulativeTotal += [the magic returning the int]
```

Thanks!

Comment: a good question would be where does this string come from? it could influence the way the answer is written, if as suggested below you are reading from a CSV, there might be a better solution for you, also, if there is a chance that there are more "constStrings" that you want to capture, or that their order could change, it should be important for us to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '....00.3276021,,,constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00...'

In [3]: re.search('constString1=(\d+);', s).group(1)
Out[3]: '31'

In [4]: re.search('constString2=(\d+);', s).group(1)
Out[4]: '16'
```

These are still strings, don't forget to convert them to integers.

Comment: Note that `\d+` will match `0123` which is not a valid integer literal (in terms of python at least).

Comment: @khachik It actually seems to be a valid integer in terms of Python: `int('0123')` returns 123.

Comment: The `int()` constructor is smart about leading 0s (and whitespace), yes. It's not being used as an integer literal, it's a string that's being converted.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, no, it isn't: `>>> 0123` causes `SyntaxError`. `int()` can handle it as `123` but the OP must make sure that is the expected behavior.

Comment: @khachik A literal `0123` won't appear when executing the code I posted. Only a string `'0123'` can possibly occur, and it will be handled in the most reasonable way I can think of.

Comment: Pedantic: `0123` isn't a syntax error in Python 2. It also doesn't have a value of 123.

Comment: @Wooble Right, but it is in Python 3. Looks like it's interpreted as octal in Python 2, interesting.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without regex.

```
def get_sub(s, start, end):
    s1 = s[s.find(start) + len(start):]
    return s1[:s1.find(end)]

get_sub(s, "constString1=", ";")
>>> '31'

get_sub(s, "constString2=", ";")
>>> '16'
```

in case that you want to cast it to another type you can do something like that:

```
def get_sub(s, start, end, cast_to):
    s1 = s[s.find(start) + len(start):]
    return cast_to(s1[:s1.find(end)])

get_sub(s,"constString1=",";", int)
>>> 31

get_sub(s,"constString2=",";", float)
>>> 16.0
```

**EDIT**

this method is actually faster than regex:

```
t1 = timeit.Timer(stmt="""get_sub(s,"constString1=",";", int)""", setup="""s = "....00.3276021,,,constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00..."
def get_sub(s, start, end, cast_to):
    s1 = s[s.find(start) + len(start):]
    return cast_to(s1[:s1.find(end)])""")

t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt="""int(re.search("constString1=(\d+);",s).group(1))""", setup="""import re
s = "....00.3276021,,,constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00..."
""")

>>> t1.timeit()
2.829952681655172

>>> t2.timeit()
3.7208872074169506
```

Comment: i like this method, but i don't think it is as effective as using a regular expression. still, its nice to see another option.

Comment: using `timeit` you can see that it is actually faster.

Comment: could you show us? timeit against what though? - i see the timeit, but that is for individual constStrings, my method does them both at the same time, should be a bit faster.

Comment: your method, wrongly assumes that `constString1` comes before `constString2`.. and is hard coded to work for specific order of keys which, in my opinion, is bad design. but if you want you can compare it with `timeit` and share your findings. And overall I think it is better to avoid regex unless really needed, just wanted to show how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the regex methods mentioned in other answers, you can use code like the following, with `split(';')` and `split('=')`, if separate items are delimited by semicolons:

```
s='....00.3276021,,,;constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00...'
string1_subtotal = string2_subtotal = 0
for ss in s.split(';'):
    a = ss.split('=')
    if a[0]=='constString1': string1_subtotal += int(a[1])
    if a[0]=='constString2': string2_subtotal += int(a[1])
```

Comment: this is definitely a way to do this, although it assumes much. however - it is very unefficient, and memory wasteful, the split will create new strings, and you are doing a lot of them. also, at a glance, its hard to see what the code is trying to do, which is one of the important things about python, sorry man, -1

Comment: Also, required altering the original string from OP to insert a ;.

Answer (score -1):

why not do it all in one pass?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "....00.3276021,,,constString1=31;garbage=00:00:00.0090000;constString2=16;garbage2=00.00..."
>>> ms = re.match(r'.*constString1=(\d+);.*constString2=(\d+);', s)
>>> ms.groups() #just to show you. you wont need to do this on your code...
('31', '16') 
>>> string1_cummulativeTotal += ms.group(1)
>>> string2_cummulativeTotal += ms.group(2)
```

note: this will only work if the `contString`'s are in the right order (1,2....)

Comment: This will work assuming that the order of `constString1` and `constString2` is the same in all strings.

Comment: well, the op did not lead me to believe otherwise. its an option, take it or leave it i guess.

Comment: Sure. The input kinda looks like csv, so it's very probable that your approach will work. But I thought it was worth to spell out the assumptions the solution is based on.

Comment: can someone at least explain why they -1 me, this is a totally acceptable answer, solving the problem raised by the OP, and it has been voted down without any reason given. am i missing something?

Comment: No idea. Upset someone recently? :) Anyway, 1 upvote compensates up to 5 downvotes :)

Comment: @InbarRose, am going to come where no-one called me. But it `seems` to me like people dont appreaciate your opinionated attitude. This is only my POV based on the fact that you had an opinion about every single question/answer/comment in this thread. Nevertheless, thanks for taking the time to provide an answer and constructive opinions.

Comment: @InbarRose - just to explain the downvote - the answer is correct but: 1) it is far less readable (readability counts) 2) it is hard-coded for this specific task it's a matter of taste but I think a more general approach has, in this case, more educational benefit

Comment: @zenpoy thank you, that actually makes sense, and i can now improve upon my future endeavors. i wish everyone could be as helpful as you... :)